# $F:X \to Y$ open continuous map when $X$ is Hausdorff and locally compact and $Y$ is Haussdorf

Tags: general-topology, compactness, open-map

$F:X \to Y$ open continuous map when $X$ is Hausdorff and locally compact and $Y$ is Haussdorf, show that $F(X)$ is locally compact.

I took some $F(x)$ for $ x\in X $ and open neighbourhood $ W \subset Y , F(x) \in W$
because of the continuity of $F$ we have $F^{-1}(W)$ as a neighbourhood of x,
because $X$ is locally compact Hausdorff I have open neighbourhood of x:  $U\subset X$
such that $x \in U \subset \overline{U}  \subset F^{-1}[W]$.

Does the map preserve containment under open map?
I know that $F[\overline{U}]$ is compact and that $F(\overline{U}) \subset \overline{F[U]}$

Does $ F(x) \in F[\overline{U}] \subset \overline{F[U]} \subset W$
 and it's enough?

Comment: What's your definition of being locally compact?

Comment: if X is Haussdorf & Locally compact it means that 
for every $x \in X$ if $W \subset X$  is a nbhd of x 
we have open subset  $U \subset  X $such that $x\in U \subset \bar U \subset W$  and $ \bar U $ is compact

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the definition, your argument is about correct: let $W$ be an open neighbourhood of $F(x) \in F[X]$. Then $x \in F^{-1}[W]$ and the latter set is open by continuity of $F$, so local compactness of $X$ gives an open neighbourhood $U$ of $x$ with $$x \in U \subseteq \overline{U} \subseteq F^{-1}[W]$$ and $\overline{U}$ compact.

But then $F[\overline{U}]$ is compact by continuity of $F$ and as images preserve inclusions:

$$F(x) \in F[U] \subseteq F[\overline{U}] \subseteq \overline{F[U]}$$

but we only know that $F[\overline{U}] \subseteq W$, but not yet for the last set. To solve that, apply the local compactness in $X$ again for $x$ and $U$ and use the $V$ we get there: $F[V]$ is as required, as $\overline{F[V]} \subseteq F[U] \subseteq W$ which is enough. I don't see that we need  Hausdorffness for $Y$ or Hausdorffness of $X$ for this proof. I suppose they're needed for local compactness.

Comment: @hardmath question was edited while I was answering. And Hausdorffness is required for local compactness in the OP's definition.